# setters are giving "typeError: not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I am passing props from parent `MoneyOut` to child `AddSupliers` and from that child to another child `SupplierNameCompont` where it is used, these props are destructured. At first instance the form works and displays what I type in the console but when I type to enter another data, it throws the TypeError, what could be the challenge, would be glad to get any help. Here is my code..

```
const MoneyOut = () => {
    const [supplierName, setSupplierName] = useState('')
    const [supplierContact, setSupplierContact] = useState(0)

   console.log(supplierContact)
   console.log(supplierName)

  return (
    <>
    <Navbar/>
    <AddSupliers setSupplierName={setSupplierName} setSupplierContact={setSupplierContact}/>
    </>
)}
export default MoneyOut

//AddSupliers

const AddSupliers = ({setSupplierName, setSupplierContact}) => {
    const [visibleX, setVisibleX] = useState(false)
    const supplierDetailsOnclick =()=>{
          setVisibleX(!visibleX)
    }
  return (
    <div>
        { !visibleX &&
        <div className='addSupplierSection'>
            <h3>SUPPLIER (optional)</h3>
            <div className='addCustomerdiv'><button className='addSuppliersBtn' 
            onClick={()=>supplierDetailsOnclick()}>+ add Supplier</button></div>
        </div>
         }
    { visibleX && <SupplierNameCompont setSupplierName={setSupplierName} setSupplierContact={setSupplierContact}/>} 
    </div>
  )
}

export default AddSupliers

// SupplierNameCompont

const SupplierNameCompont = ({setSupplierName,setSupplierContact}) => {

    const [visible2, setVisible2] = useState(false)

    return (
    <>
       {!visible2 && 
       <div className='supplierNameSection'>
            <div>
                <h3>SUPPLIER NAME</h3>
            </div>

            <div>
                <form id='suppliersName'>
                    <input type='text' className='suppliersName'
                        placeholder='e.g. Mr John' onChange={(e)=>{setSupplierName(e.target.value)}}/>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>SUPPLIER CONTACT</h3>
            </div>

            <div>
                <form id='suppliersContact'>
                    <input type='number' className='suppliersContact'
                        placeholder='e.g. 0810...' onChange={(e)=>{setSupplierContact(e.target.value)}}/>
                </form>
            </div>
            <hr className='borderline1'/>
            <div className='saveSuppliersBtnDiv'><button className='saveSuppliersBtn' onClick={()=>{setVisible2(!visible2)}}>+ Add</button></div>
        </div>}
        {visible2 && <AddSupliers/>}
    </>
    )
}

export default SupplierNameCompont
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the problem, you should never render a new instance of AddSupliers when the "+ Add" button is clicked. Instead, handle the visibility state in the MoneyOut component and draw the SupplierNameCompont component based on whether it is visible or not.

Here's the updated code, let me know if it works:

```
const MoneyOut = () => {
    const [supplierName, setSupplierName] = useState('');
    const [supplierContact, setSupplierContact] = useState(0);
    const [showSupplierComponent, setShowSupplierComponent] = useState(false);

    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            <AddSupliers
                setSupplierName={setSupplierName}
                setSupplierContact={setSupplierContact}
                setShowSupplierComponent={setShowSupplierComponent}
            />
            {showSupplierComponent && <SupplierNameCompont setSupplierName={setSupplierName} setSupplierContact={setSupplierContact} />}
        </>
    );
};

export default MoneyOut;


const AddSupliers = ({ setSupplierName, setSupplierContact, setShowSupplierComponent }) => {
    const [visibleX, setVisibleX] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div>
            {!visibleX && (
                <div className='addSupplierSection'>
                    <h3>SUPPLIER (optional)</h3>
                    <div className='addCustomerdiv'>
                        <button className='addSuppliersBtn' onClick={() => setShowSupplierComponent(true)}>+ add Supplier</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default AddSupliers;
```

Comment: thank you for your input, I have tried it but the problem still persists.

Comment: Good!! thanks it finally worked, your input was the solution, I just needed to fix some typo and boom!!! it worked, thanks @Lashen

Comment: All good @Aham_Uzoma